# Configuring Postgres with OpenSSL and '--with-openssl' option

Tags: postgresql, openssl, autoconf

I tried installing Postgres with OpenSSL by doing

`./configure --with-openssl`

but I got an error saying

> configure: error: header file openssl/ssl.h is required for OpenSSL

However, I do have OpenSSL installed.  If I run `openssl version` I get this output

> OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

I came across [this solution](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5627D2A2.1020904@joeconway.com) and tried doing

`./configure --with-includes=/usr/local/ssl/include` and it installed without any problems.

Can someone explain whats going on and the difference between the two configure versions?

Comment: Having openssl installed does not mean the development files are installed. Linux distros split libraries into separate packages for mere usage and development, for instance libssl-dev for openssl on debian-based systems.

Answer (score 6):

> Can someone explain whats going on and the difference between the two configure versions.

You can run `./configure --help` to get a synopsis of arguments:

```
$ ./configure --help | egrep -i '(ssl|includes)'
  --with-includes=DIRS    look for additional header files in DIRS
  --with-openssl          build with OpenSSL support
```

---

> `./configure --with-openssl`

This simply enables OpenSSL in Postgres. It enables checking in Autoconf, like probing for symbols `CRYPTO_new_ex_data` and `SSL_Library_init`.

It also looks like configure defines `#define USE_OPENSSL 1` which activates OpenSSL code paths:

```
$ grep -IR OPENSSL * | grep '.c'
...
src/backend/postmaster/fork_process.c:#ifdef USE_OPENSSL
src/backend/postmaster/fork_process.c:#ifdef USE_OPENSSL
src/backend/utils/init/postinit.c:#ifdef USE_OPENSSL
src/backend/utils/init/postinit.c:#ifdef USE_OPENSSL
src/include/libpq/libpq-be.h:#ifdef USE_OPENSSL
src/include/libpq/libpq-be.h:#ifdef USE_OPENSSL
...
```

---

> `./configure --with-includes=/usr/local/ssl/include`

This probably did *not* enable OpenSSL. It simply added a path for headers that were not used during compilation. Use `ldd`on Linux and `otool -L` on OS X to see if there are any OpenSSL dependencies.

---

You should probably use `./configure --with-openssl --with-includes=/usr/local/ssl/include --with-libraries=/usr/local/ssl/lib`. You should probably add `CFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib` to ensure proper runtime linking.

Also see [Postgres Issue 14308: Postgres 9.5.4 does not configure against OpenSSL 1.1.0](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160902061034.15676.31081@wrigleys.postgresql.org)

Comment: So I installed OpenSSL by following the instructions in the Install file.  However, my `/usr/local/ssl` directory doesn't contain a `lib` folder or a `include` folder.

Comment: @Brosef - If you need help building and installing OpenSSL on a platform, then you should ask another question. Please state the platform (OS X?). I *almost* provided the recipe for OpenSSL and Postgres, but the question did not lend itself to the recipe because its for Postgres/Autoconf and the platform was missing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  When I try your solution with my paths I get the error "configure: error: library 'ssl' is required for OpenSSL".  I have to run `./configure --with-openssl --with-includes=/usr/local/include/openssl --with-libraries=/usr/local/lib`.  For some reason my `lib` and `include` aren't contained within `/usr/local/ssl` instead they're located at `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`

Comment: I've been overlooking that link you provided at the bottom.  It looks like I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Brosef - Also see [How to tell Autoconf “require symbol A or B” from LIB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39285733) I don't know Autoconf (I still write my own makefiles) so I don't know how to proceed. Once configuration is complete, the port to OpenSSL 1.1.0 can proceed. That should be relatively pain free as long as Postgres is not being too clever with OpenSSL.

Comment: So you're having the same problem?  I thought I was doing something very wrong.  I'm thinking of giving up installing postgres myself and using homebrew instead.

Comment: @Brosef - use OpenSSL 1.0.2 until the Postgres folks add the support. There's no material difference between OpenSSL 1.1.0 and 1.0.2 with respect to TLS in Postgres. Plus, Homebrew will most likely supply OpenSSL 1.0.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122598/discussion-between-brosef-and-jww).

Comment: I was cross compiling on x86 host for aarch64 target, was unable to find ssl libs despite having cross compiled them and specifying header path with `--with-includes`, adding `--with-libraries` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install OpenSSL-devel it will give you all dependencies. It's helped me.

In CenotOS/Redhat

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```